# Animate image on click HTML

Tags: html, css, animation

Is there a way in which a person clicks on the text `Hello` and it slides down an dims out?? and on phone they should be able to just pull it down and it gets dimed and slides down??

Summarizing the question

1: Click on text to make the dive slide down and dim out??
 2: For `Mobile` pull the div out of the screen and dim it out by hand??

```css
#home_main_main {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border: 3px solid darkgrey;
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  height: 80%;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

b {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="home_main_main"><br>
    <b>&nbsp;Hello</b>
</div>
```

Comment: You should open a separate question for your "animation" and add some code what you already tried.

Comment: @jona Would you answer that one if I created?

Comment: I can look into it, but I think you will need javascript for it because it should happen on click and not only on hover.

Comment: no problem i can use js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border will be set around your element. Currently your element already has a width of 100%.
One way to fix this would be to subtract the border from the with using `calc`

```css
#home_main_main {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border: 3px solid darkgrey;
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  height: 80%;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

b {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="home_main_main"><br>
    <b>&nbsp;Hello</b>
</div>
```

*Remember that your border is on both sides of your element. With a 3px border it will be in total 6px of width that has to be removed of your 100%.*

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `box-sizing` property for all elements.

Using `box-sizing: border-box;`, the width is inclusive of `padding` and `border` values.

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

#home_main_main {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border: 3px solid darkgrey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

b {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="home_main_main"><br>
    <b>&nbsp;Hello</b>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.body {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
  #home_main_main{
  position : absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:80%;
  }
  .b{
    font: as you like ;
    
 }
```

```html
<div id="home_main_main"><br>
    <b>&nbsp;Hello</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working

Comment: `overflow: hidden` will just remove any vertical scroll but won't fix the problem.

Comment: any borde or background out of the size of your div will be removed

Comment: @pycrypt Yes, it will be removed. But it wont display inside like op wants it

Comment: set body width : 100% and height:100 , position : relative , will work